# Почему Simple HTML DOM не находит отдельные объекты?

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста... Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Пытаюсь парсить следующую страницу: http://superdeals.aliexpress.com/en

Необходимо достать div class="pro-msg" который хранится в li с class list-items.
Однако получается так, что далеко не все данные отображаются на странице. Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$base = 'http://superdeals.aliexpress.com/en?spm=2114.11010108.21.1.v65LIL';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($str);

    $res=$html->find('div.pro-msg', 0)->outertext;
    echo $res;
```

То есть Simple HTML DOM даже не видит отдельные части страницы, исполнение кода = пустой странице, ставлю дургой div - все работает. Если парсить всю страницу file_get_html, то естественным образом отображается далеко не весь сайт. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно обойти проблему.

Заранее спасибо большое!

Comment: Если вы смотрели HTML код страницы, то вам должно быть понятно в чем проблема. `div class="pro-msg"` находится внутри шаблона [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), т.е. выводится через Javascript. Так что Simple HTML DOM вам здесь не поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, быть может подскажете, что в данном случае может помочь?

Comment: Очевидно ручной парсинг. [Рег. выражения](http://fi2.php.net/manual/ru/book.pcre.php) вам в помощь.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроме голого HTML на странице есть скрипты, которые догружают данные с сервера. Содержимое `div.pro-msg` заполняется одним из скриптов.

Беглый осмотр показал, что нужно смотреть на `SuperdealSingle.getSingleData()`. В этой функции происходит заполнение шаблона после запроса к серверу с адресом типа `http://api.dos.aliexpress.com/aliexpress/data/doQuery.jsonp?...`. Запросы к данной странице не блокируются и вроде не имеют никакой привязки к авторизации. Вы можете брать параметры для запроса после парсинга HTML, потом обращаться к вышеуказанному адресу с нужными значениями и получать нужные вам данные в виде JSONP.

Например вот что получаем при соответствующем запросе (добавлено форматирование кода):

```
jQuery1830848040385870263_1449156061907({
    "content": {
        "success": true,
        "statusCode": 200,
        "errorContext": {
            "errrors": [],
            "warns": []
        },
        "nodeList": [{
            "name": "Single",
            "id": 140243,
            "modules": [{
                "name": "Single",
                "id": 126968,
                "custSortRules": [{
                    "field": "product_min_price",
                    "dir": "asc_desc"
                }, {
                    "field": "promotion_discount",
                    "dir": "desc"
                }, {
                    "field": "total_weight_score",
                    "dir": "desc"
                }, {
                    "field": "trade_count",
                    "dir": "desc"
                }]
            }],
            "nodeData": {
                "totalCount": 1,
                "dataList": [{
                    "id": 32353413340,
                    "unit": "piece",
                    "imgUrl": "http:\/\/g03.a.alicdn.com\/kf\/HTB1F3NYJpXXXXcjXXXXq6xXFXXXS\/children-boy-spring-autumn-jacket-coat-kid-boy-brand-leather-jacekt-outerwear-for-boy-black-leather.jpg_350x350.jpg",
                    "sdom": "101.140243.126968.0_32353413340",
                    "title": "Boy's Coat",
                    "minPrice": "US $32.48",
                    "minPromPrice": "US $9.74",
                    "minMobPromPrice": "US $9.74",
                    "discount": 70,
                    "mobDiscount": 70,
                    "isMobDiscount": false,
                    "isSoldOut": false,
                    "detailUrl": "http:\/\/www.aliexpress.com\/item\/children-boy-spring-autumn-jacket-coat-kid-boy-brand-leather-jacekt-outerwear-for-boy-black-leather\/32353413340.html?sdom=101.140243.126968.0_32353413340",
                    "orderNum": 117,
                    "storeDetailUrl": "http:\/\/www.aliexpress.com\/store\/product\/children-boy-spring-autumn-jacket-coat-kid-boy-brand-leather-jacekt-outerwear-for-boy-black-leather\/1761395_32353413340.html?sdom=101.140243.126968.0_32353413340",
                    "stockNum": 480
                }],
                "isEnd": true,
                "extraData": {}
            },
            "extraProps": {
                "descr": ">  Synthetic leather<br\/>> Motor jacket style<br\/>> Available in black and red"
            },
            "leaf": false
        }]
    },
    "hasError": false
});
```

Здесь видны все необходимые вам данные.

Если возникнут проблемы, придется более глубоко покопаться в скриптах.

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ ЧЕЛОВЕЧЕСКОЕ СПАСИБО!!! Единственное, если не сложно, буду чрезмерно признателен за какие-нибудь приближенные примеры или ссылки на материалы, чтобы понять принципы взаимодействия))

Comment: Вы написали немного раньше чем я) СПАСИБО!!!!

Comment: @ArtyomSosonko Насчет примеров не знаю что написать. Тут два направления: 1. парсинг HTML; 2. реверс-инжиниринг запросов к API. Первое достаточно тривиально, второе наверное не может иметь инструкций и материалов. Только кропотливая работа с постоянным тестированием полученного результата.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!)